# Serializing a C struct in Python and sending over a socket

Tags: python, c, sockets, serialization, ctypes

I'm trying to serializing the following C struct

```
struct packet
{
    int id;
    unsigned char *ce;
    unsigned char *syms;
};
```

in Python and send it over a socket. The number of elements pointed by `ce` and `syms` are known to be `N`. Currently I'm doing this way. First, I wrap the struct using ctypes to

```
class Packet(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("id",  c_int),
                ("ce", POINTER(c_ubyte)),
                ("syms", POINTER(c_ubyte))]
```

Then, I populate an object of the following class using its `fill_data` function from a `ctypes.POINTER(Packet)`:

```
class DataLoad:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = -1
        self.ce = []
        self.syms = []

    def fill_data(self, pkt_p):
        """ pkt_p is POINTER(Packet)
        """
        self.id = pkt_p.contents.id
        self.ce = []
        for i in range(N):
            self.ce.append(pkt_p.contents.ce[i])
        self.syms = []
        for i in range(N):
            self.syms.append(pkt_p.contents.syms[i])
```

Finally, I simply use `pickle.dumps(DataLoad)` to generate a byte stream and send.

This approach works well. However, it seems to be quite slow. One reason I can see is that `pickle.dumps` bring much overhead. For example, if the C struct is only 1024 bytes, I may have to send almost 4000 bytes for each struct using pickle. Also, packing/populating DataLoad also takes time.

So my question is, do I have other better choices to serialize this C struct in python and send? I would prefer to avoid pickle and populate a separate class instance. Thanks.

Comment: do it in c and use cython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out the following way to manually serialize the `Packet' instance without using pickle.

```
def serialize(pkt_p, size_g, size_p):
    """ Serialize Packet instance
        size_g - number of elements pointed by ce
        size_p - number of elements pointed by syms
        Return a byte stream
    """ 
    pktstr = b''
    pktstr += struct.pack('i', pkt_p.contents.id)
    pktstr += string_at(pkt_p.contents.ce, size_g)
    pktstr += string_at(pkt_p.contents.syms, size_p)
    return pktstr

def deserialize(pkt_p, pktstr, size_g, size_p):
    """ De-serialize pktstr and fill a POINTER(Packet)
    """
    pkt_p.contents.id = struct.unpack('i', pktstr[0:4])[0]
    ce = (c_ubyte * size_g).from_buffer_copy(pktstr[4:4+size_g])
    pkt_p.contents.ce = cast(ce, POINTER(c_ubyte))
    syms = (c_ubyte * size_p).from_buffer_copy(pktstr[-size_p:])
    pkt_p.contents.syms = cast(syms, POINTER(c_ubyte))
```

The `string_at()` and the `from_buffer_copy()` functions are the key.

Comment: Using `pktbuf = bytearray()` allows the bufer to grow in place (i.e. C `realloc`) with the `+=` operations.

Comment: Also, in `serialize` using `struct.pack` and `string_at` is unnecessary. All ctypes objects implement the buffer protocol. They can be appended directly to the `bytearray`, e.g. `pktbuf += pkt_p[0].id`. For the pointers, create a `c_char` array *without copying* to a new string (unlike `string_at`), so it only has to get copied once to store it in the buffer, e.g. `pktbuf += cast(pkt_p[0].ce, POINTER(c_char * size_g))[0]`.

Comment: In `deserialize` you can use `pkt_p[0].id = c_int.from_buffer_copy(pktstr)` instead of `struct.unpack`. For the arrays you should use the `offset` parameter of `from_buffer_copy` to avoid the temporary copy made by a slice, and you don't need the intervening `cast`, e.g. `pkt_p[0].ce = (c_ubyte * size_g).from_buffer_copy(pktstr, sizeof(c_int))` and `pkt_p[0].syms = (c_ubyte * size_p).from_buffer_copy(pktstr, sizeof(c_int) + size_g)`.

Comment: @eryksun, these are really helpful suggestions on the performance of the code! Learnt a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you know the number of elements to be N, I would suggest changing your structure to this:

```
class Packet(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("id", c_int),
                ("ce", c_ubyte * N),
                ("syms", c_ubyte * N)]
```

Next, if you only want to send the struct data, you don't need to pickle the whole thing. Just send the packet data:

```
p = Packet()
p.id = 555
...
# cast the struct to a pointer to a char array
pdata = ctypes.cast(ctypes.byref(p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char * ctypes.sizeof(p)))
# now you can just save/send the struct data
someSocketObject.send(pdata.contents.raw)
```

To read the data on the other side:

```
p = Packet()
raw = someSocketObject.read(ctypes.sizeof(p))
ctypes.memmove(ctypes.pointer(p),raw,ctypes.sizeof(p))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I know the number of elements is a fixed number in Python, I cannot change the format of the C struct because the length of `ce` and `syms` need to be dynamically allocated in C. Under this restriction, can I still define `Packet` the way you proposed?

Comment: Probably, but it depends. If you do a naive dump of your original Packet struct in a C program, it will write out an int, followed by two pointers. The data for the `ce` and `syms` fields will be kept elsewhere. However, most useful C programs would actually be written to dump the data, rather than the values of the pointers. If you are only exchanging data between python programs, then you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @YeLi, no you cannot use this `Packet` definition. `POINTER(c_ubyte)` is 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the pointer size. `c_ubyte * N`  is N bytes. You also can't send the struct as a buffer (BTW, the pointer cast is unnecessary; ctypes objects support the buffer protocol) because the pointers are meaningless outside of your process. You need to create a new buffer that has the `id`, array size N, and data arrays concatenated. I'd use a `bytearray`.

Comment: @erysun, thanks for pointing this out. Yes, you're correct. I had to serialize the bytes pointed by `ce` and `syms` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Packer is an repository to serialize and unserialize data, works for python and C.

https://github.com/souzomain/Packer

```py
from Packer import Packer, Parser

packer = Packer()
packer.add_str("hello world")

print(f"packet size: {packer.get_size()} | packet: {packer.get_buffer()}")

parser = Parser(packer.get_buffer(), packer.get_size())
print(parser.parse_str())
```